# Java convert byte[] to InputStream with new line after each array entry

Tags: java, arrays, newline, inputstream

Say I have a byte array like,

```
byte[] byteArray = { 'm', 'e', 'o', 'w'};
```

I'm converting this to `InputStream` using,

```
new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray)
```

But I want the resultant `InputStream` to add a new line after each array entry like

```
m
e
o
w
```

How can I achieve this in an efficient way. The byte array could have 100s to 1000s of entries?

Comment: 100s to 1000s of bytes is not worth worrying about efficiency-wise.  If you had 1000000 elements it _might_ be worth thinking about.  I probably wouldn't worry until there were a few more zeros on top of that.

Comment: Understood. Forgetting the efficiency, how can I get the required result  LouisWasserman@

Comment: *But I want the resultant InputStream to add a new line after each array entry*. Line separators are a 'view level' thing. You would add the line separator to view in a file or console using a ```PrintWriter```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The efficient way to do it would be to create another byte[]

```
byte[] byteArray = ...;
byte[] newBytes = new byte[byteArray.length *2];
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
  newBytes[i*2] = byteArray[i];
  newBytes[i*2 + 1] = '\n';
}
```

Comment: Note: This will only work with text that is utf-8/latin-1/ascii encoded, and only if every character is just one byte